# FESTassertThat() method incorrect behavior

Tags: java, assert, fest

I'm running the assertThat() method in the FEST library. But don't understand the runtime behaviour for the code below which runs in a while loop.

```
assertThat(Priority >= nextPriority);
```

At runtime  Priority = 1 and nextPriority = 2, but when I debug this statement the method, the method doesn't exit but continues to the next line within the while loop.

Does anyone know why this happenns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertThat()` doesn't verify any assertion. What you want is

```
assertThat(priority >= nextPriority).isTrue();
```

or better:

```
assertThat(priority).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(nextPriority);
```